# Uninstall Eclipse

Tags: uninstall, eclipse

I'm trying to uninstall eclipse IDE, when I run

```
sudo apt-get autoremove eclipse*
```

I get

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package eclipse-workspace
```

Could anyone help me to uninstall eclipse?

Thanks.

Comment: where is it installed? what does `which eclipse` output?

Comment: It's installed in Home. `which eclipse` doesn't give any output.

Comment: then it is not installed using apt.. and is not managed by package manager.. You can just delete the folder and any shortcuts you may have created

Comment: @zanna sure..  Will try to make a detailed answer and post soon

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`apt-get autoremove eclipse` works if you have installed the application through apt package manager.

By your comments you seem to have downloaded the eclipse package and extracted it in the home directory (Manual Installation).
In this case you can directly delete the `eclipse` folder set in your directory.

```
sudo rm -rf ~/eclipse
```

**Things to keep in mind for custom install**

- If you have set `eclipse` for command line using a symlink in `bin` folder you will need to remove it manually. eg:

  ```
  sudo rm /usr/local/bin/eclipse
  ```
- If you created a desktop shortcut file you will have to delete it separately.

Comment: I had `~/.eclipse` hidden folder that I deleted too

Answer (score 0):

There are two methods to install eclipse

1: By downloading form website and extracting and operating without involving registries.

2: From the Terminal by entering `sudo apt-get install eclipse`

If you have installed it using the first method then you have to manually remove the directory where you installed Eclipse. Which Include the Eclipse workspace and Eclipse Directory.

And if you have installed it using the Terminal method.
Then the best method will be to first install synaptic package manager by typing `sudo apt-get install synaptic` afterward opening synaptic search Eclipse and the Packages will appear. The one with the green box are installed right click on them and select complete removal. Do this for all remaining packages and apply. It will completely remove the eclipse form the system.

- Have a good day.